# Get document collection in azure db?

Tags: c#, azure

Using Azure DB in a cloud function I have the following:

```
 var client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endPoint), primaryKey);
            var collUrl = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("id", "course");

            var doc = (await client.ReadDocumentCollectionAsync(collUrl)).Resource;
```

doc is a DocumentCollection but it doesn't look like there's any way to access an enumerator or something to view the contents so I might be in the wrong place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> doc is a DocumentCollection

As you metioned that doc is a documentCollection, more details please refer to 
[DocumentClient.ReadDocumentCollectionAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.readdocumentcollectionasync?view=azure-dotnet) Method is used to read a DocumentCollection from the Azure Cosmos DB service as an asynchronous operation.

> but it doesn't look like there's any way to access an enumerator or something to view the contents so I might be in the wrong place?

If you want to list the documents in the collection, we could use [DocumentClient.CreateDocumentQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.createdocumentquery?view=azure-dotnet) Method to do that. We also could get the demo code from [github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/blob/f374cc601f4cf08d11c88f0c3fa7dcefaf7ecfe8/samples/code-samples/DocumentManagement/Program.cs#L248-L251)

```
   var doc = (await client.ReadDocumentCollectionAsync(collUrl)).Resource;
   var documents = client.CreateDocumentQuery(doc.SelfLink).AsEnumerable().ToList();
```

[image]

Comment: If it is a partitioned collection, you must also specify either a partition key or enable cross-partition query.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell there is no iterator on the collection itself. You can, however, create a query on the collection like this:

```
var docs = client.CreateDocumentQuery(collUrl);
foreach (var document in docs)
{
    // Do stuff with your document
}
```

Please note there are a lot of overloads for `CreateDocumentQuery` at this time.